# PyQt4, PyQt5 or PySide for Matplotlib on Archlinux

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pip, archlinux

I cannot use matplotlib anymore (on python 3.5, archlinux, kde). After a system update with pacman I got an error that PySide is not installed. When I unsuccessfully tried to install it using pip3, I found out that since PySide version 1.2.4, python 3.5 is explicitly unsupported. So after some research, I found out that PyQt4 or PyQt5 should work as well. When I try to install PyQt4 or 5 with pip3, I get the following message

```
$ sudo pip3 install PyQt5
Collecting PyQt5
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt5
```

qmake --version returns

```
$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib
```

Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Why the heck are you doing **system** installs with **pip** on archlinux? The latest versions of all these packages are already in the official archlinux repositories.

Comment: because when I initially tried to install everything via pacman I could not get jupyter to work properly. 
And by 'everything' I mean ipython and jupyter :)

Comment: Those two packages are also in the official archlinux repositories. Are you claiming that they are broken? If so, you should be making a bug report on the official archlinux tracker.

Comment: When I tried to install jupyter and ipython with pacman a couple of months ago I couldn't get jupyter to work. I don't remember what the problem was exactly. I just needed a quick solution, so I tried to install via pip as an alternative and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I think in my pacman install I had problems with the python versions (2.7 and 3.5), which were very easy to avoid by use of pip and pip3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. In another thread on PyQt4 installation problems  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip) I found the useful comment by Ivo that, on Linux, one should install the PyQt packages using the native package manager. So I installed PyQt4 and PyQt5 with pacman and now everything seems to work fine.

Note: It was necessary to reset the kernel first. Otherwise I just got a new error message.