# PyQt4 and tkinter unable to install

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, pyqt4

I am trying to install tkinter or PyQt4. But it says it could not find the version that satisfies. I tried to look google but could not find a method that works for me. Has any one faced this issue or know what could be the resolution. Here below are the details

(E2) [user@hostname bin]$ pip install PyQt4

Collecting PyQt4
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt4

(E2) [user@hostname bin]$ virtualenv --version

15.1.0

(E2) [user@hostname bin]$ python

Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr 29 2017, 18:05:01) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > quit()
> > >       (E2) [user@hostname bin]$

Comment: PyQt is not in available as a pip package
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip

Comment: try with: `sudo yum install PyQt4`

Answer (score 0):

Download the unofficial binary package [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4)

Now, head over to folder where the file is saved and press down shift and right click. Select "Open command line here"

Type and run:

```
pip install [Name of file]
```

For example, if I downloaded the file PyQwt‑5.2.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

I would write

```
pip install PyQwt‑5.2.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
```