# plotting too many lines in matplotlib: out of memory

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot ~2000x300 lines within a single plot.
e.g. something like that, but with 300 curves (each of 2000 datapoints) instead of four shown here:
[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7rvw.png)

First I set up the figure:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
```

Then I do the following for many times:

```
drawnLine = plt.Line2D([Xstart, Xfinish], [Ystart,Yfinish], 1, linestyle='solid', color='b')
ax.add_artist(drawnLine)
```

and in the end I wanted to do:

```
fig.savefig(ExpFolder + 'NewFig.png')
```

However the script reaches the 8GB memory limits and stops.

Comment: You really need all 2000 data-points? Smoothing or subsampling is not acceptable?

Comment: You can surely try using a [`LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/line_collection2.html) instead of individual lines. This will be much more efficient. (If it is sufficient to get below the memory limit,however, I can't know) If you have problems with that, provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, matplotlib isn't the most memory-efficient library in the world.

Now, 600,000 segments really *is* a lot if you do it in pure unadulterated naive software drawing so, hm, not cool.

What I'd propose is that you abandon matplotlib's canvas methods for either:

- consider a fixed image size (in pixels), and directly render the lines onto that canvas. You can do that with some tricks for images that you show with `matplotlib`'s `imagesc` and consorts, but really, you're not making your life easier at that point. So pick any python library that allows you to paint pixels onto a bitmap. There's some.
- Consider something that doesn't try to draw 600,000 lines in software – I'm thinking of simply directly talking to your graphics hardware.
- Simply use something *less* inefficient than matplotlib. I like `pyqtgraph`.

`pyqtgraph` example:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
import numpy
N=20
x = numpy.random.poisson(lam=0.01, size=(N,2000))
y = numpy.random.normal(size=(N,2000))
p = pg.plot()
for x_,y_ in zip(x,y):
    p.addItem(pg.PlotDataItem(x_,y_))
QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am actually having a problem to install PyQt4 for win_x64. Is it possible to replace this package with something? I am sorry for asking simple questions, I am having zero experience on python's graphics.

Comment: @PetyaLidsky I've not used windows for a long time, but shouldn't the Windows amd64 installer from http://www.pyqtgraph.org/  be exactly what you need?

Comment: and for the pyqt4 / Q4 dependency, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody. 
In the end the optimal solution was with use of matplotlib.collections as it was suggested by ImportanceOfBeingErnest.
[image: Image full]