# How to install PyQt4 on Windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 (Spyder3) and I'm unable to import PyQt4?
I have tried the following

```
pip install PyQt4

pip install python-qt4

conda install PyQt4

conda install python-qt4
```

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python_qt4 (from versi
>   ons: )
>   No matching distribution found for python_qt4

Similar error for all 
None works

Comment: you should print the error you receive.

Comment: Use the one by [Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4), I also had problems with pip. Or use a Python distribution like Anaconda, PyQt comes with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install PyQt4 on Windows using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip)

Comment: [github has the isuess](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2157), you can know more about it, and the question has been asked before and already has an answer

Answer (score 6):

[How to install PyQt4 on Windows using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip)

Download the right .whl file for your OS from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4
And use `pip install filename.whl`

Comment: I have tried this earlier, shows the following error `PyQt4-4.11.4-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` @Hjalte J.

Comment: Have you tried the one for CPython2.7 ?
PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 1):

you can download it from [here](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) and compile it

pip download [isuess](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2157) tell you, I think it can help you.

hopes to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: PyQt4-4.11.4-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this
>   platform.

My system type is 64 bit, But to solve this error I have installed PyQt4 of 32 bit windows system, i.e [PyQt4-4.11.4-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4) - [click here to see more versions](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4).

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzwkz.jpg)

Kindly select appropriate version of PyQt4 according to your installed python version.