# Why can't I install PyQt4 through pycharm?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have been trying to install and use `pyqt4` but I just don't know how

- I tried through `pip` but it seems this won't work
- I tried through `pycharm` and this error appears

I have updated pip but for some reason, it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A similar question on Stack Overflow seems to have a similar problem and has great answers addressed in it:

[How to install PyQt4 on Windows using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip#22651895)

Another option for installing PyQt-4 is using pip installation of the unofficial binaries found here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4