# use correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I am using pycharm , i am having this error by adding any package , [Click Here](http://prntscr.com/k90z2q)

i have tried lot of methods , but didn't succeed yet.

Info :

1. python 3.6.2
2. pip 10.0.1
3. VirtualEnv

Comment: Have you tried installing the package using pip from the command line? Have it given you any error?

Comment: yes i have tried http://prntscr.com/k913is

Comment: This is not a problem with the version.

Comment: The package `gui` just does not exists. Where did you get that name from?

Comment: i just can't add any package : http://prntscr.com/k914tt

Comment: Again, `PyQt4` does not exist. Try `pip install pygame`

Comment: yeah its downloading ,

Comment: Both `gui` and `PyQt4` don't exists. From where did you get the name `gui`?

Comment: They are available in the Available package list : http://prntscr.com/k919ng

Comment: For `PyQt4`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip

Comment: For `gui`: This is an empty project (look at the project page) There is nothing to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use pip to install these packages for different reasons:

- `PyQt4`: This can't be installed with `pip` because it is to complex ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip) is a full explanation with workarounds)
- `gui` is an empty package without content. There just is nothing to install. Look at the [project page](https://pypi.org/project/gui/): No homepacke, no download button no source code