# any guidance when installing pyrcc4?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

How to do this through pip install? I think that i need to install pyqt dev tools but not sure on what the command is for that when using the windows command prompt. What is the command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install PyQt4 on Windows using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip)

Comment: if you have PyQt4 installed this already has that application.