# Can I automate browsing a dynamic website without opening a browser?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I got into automating tasks on the web using python.
I have tried requests/urllib3/requests-html but they don't get me the right elements, because they get only the `html` (not the updated version with `javascript`).
Some recommended Selenium, but it opens a browser with the `webdriver`.
I need a way to get elements after they get updated, and maybe after they get updated for a second time.
The reason I don't want it to open a browser is I'm running my script on a hosting-scripts service.

Comment: Please can you share an [mcve]. Where is some code and a test URL/HTML ?

Comment: A little late, but I found https://woob.tech interesting, full browser without webdriver / local browser install.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you look into the `--headless` option in webdriver, but that will probably not work for you, since this still requires the browser installed so webdriver can make use of the browsers rendering engine ("headless" means it does not start the UI). Since your hosting service will probably not have the browser executables installed this will not work.

Without a rendering engine you will not get the rendered (and JS-enhanced) web page, that simply does not work in pure python.

On option would be a service like [saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/) (I am not affiliated, but I am a happy user) who run browsers on their infrastructure and allow you to control them via their API. So you can run selenium scripts that get the HTML/JS content via RemoteWebDriver and process the results on your own server.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Solution to your problem.

Beautiful Soup doesn't mimic a client. Javascript is code that runs on the client. With Python, we simply make a request to the server, and get the server's response, along of course with the javascript, but it's the browser that reads and runs that javascript. Thus, we need to do that. There are many ways to do this. If you're on Mac or Linux, you can setup dryscrape... or we can just do basically what dryscrape does in PyQt4.

```
    import sys
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
    from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
    from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
    import bs4 as bs
    import urllib.request

    class Client(QWebPage):

        def __init__(self, url):
            self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
            QWebPage.__init__(self)
            self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
            self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
            self.app.exec_()

        def on_page_load(self):
            self.app.quit()

    url = 'https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/'
    client_response = Client(url)
    source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    js_test = soup.find('p', class_='jstest')
    print(js_test.text)
```

Just in case you wanted to make use of dryscrape:

```
    import dryscrape

   sess = dryscrape.Session()
   sess.visit('https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/')
   source = sess.body()

   soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
   js_test = soup.find('p', class_='jstest')
   print(js_test.text)
```

Comment: I already tried PyQt4, but there's always `No module named PyQt4` error.

Comment: pip install PyQt4 Works like a charm for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip