# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: )

Tags: python, pip, installation, qt4

When trying to install qt4 for python 2.7 (that I need to run some scripts written by other developers):

```
$ sudo pip install PyQt4

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt4
```

Additional information:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.15+

$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
numpy      1.16.5 
pip        19.3   
pyqtgraph  0.10.0 
setuptools 41.4.0 
wheel      0.33.6
```

Any suggestion on how to install it?

**Please note** that I have tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip):

```
pip install PyQt4-4.11.4-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl

ERROR: PyQt4-4.11.4-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I guess because it is not a windows platform, isn't it? I am trying to install it on XUbuntu 18.04.

As suggested in one of the comment by @phd *"PyQt4-4.11.4-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl is for Python 3.5 and Python 64-bit. You need to download wheel for Python 2.7"*.

I have tryed also:

```
$ pip install PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl

Requirement 'PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.
```

So the question can be: how to install the right version? How to find the right packet? My problem is exactly this one: I do not know how to move myself in this big forest. Thank you for every suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install PyQt4 on Windows using pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip)

Comment: I have tried the solution in that answers: they do not solve the problem. I am updating the question to clarify it

Comment: `PyQt4-4.11.4-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl` is for Python 3.5 and Python 64-bit. You need to download wheel for Python 2.7.

Comment: @phd Question updated. I have tried also with the 2.7

Comment: "*looks like a filename, but the file does not exist*" Provde the correct path to the downloaded file.

Comment: @phd, you are absolutely right. The problem, as explained in the question, is that I do not know (1) how to find packets that cannot be installed through `pip` or `conda install` and (2) how to find the right path in this specific case

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Can I ask questions about installation in SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338203/can-i-ask-questions-about-installation-in-so) Software tools commonly used by programmers and is **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.**

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, should I delete the question?

Comment: That's up to you.  I doubt it will get a useful answer and it's probably going to be closed.

Answer (score 5):

Building on [sinoroc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11138259/sinoroc)'s answer: PyQt4 is outdated, and only PyQt6 or PyQt5 are available on PIP. See this [website](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download).

```
pip install PyQt6
```

Comment: Well that was 1000x more useful to me than the existing answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

By default *pip* looks for project distributions on [Pypi](https://pypi.org). If you ask for `pip install PyQt4`, then you can also manually look at [the page for this *PyQt4* project on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt4/). There you will eventually see that there are no distributions at all to download so *pip* won't be able to install anything on any platform for any Python version at all. You need to look for alternatives.

You can have a look at the [homepage of the PyQt project](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/) and you will eventually find the page to [download the PyQt4 source code](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download). There is a [link on this page for the Linux source code of PyQt4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.12.3/PyQt4_gpl_x11-4.12.3.tar.gz), so you might want to have a look at it and see if you can get it installed on your system.