# Sip for python 2.7 and PyQt4 on Windows 10

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to run one of our old Python 2.7 and Qt4 applications, which runs under Linux, on Windows.

I am having difficulty installing sip for Python 2.7 on Windows 10.

pip does not seem to find it.

I downloaded the zip from riverback and did 'python configure.py' and whilst that output sensible looking messages I still can't do 'import sip'.

There are a few similiar questions on Stack Overflow but no useful answers. Some just say 'use the wheel' which isn't very helpful.

Any help gratefully received.

Thanks to eyllansec, this works:

1) download wheel from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4
2) pip install PyQt4-4.11.4-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: Could you please post any specific commands that you try to execute & their output?

Comment: IIRC PyQt is only available with Pip from Python 3.5 and higher. Perhaps installing the [Anaconda Python Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) is an option? It comes with PyQt installed.

Comment: PyQt4 has been deprecated for years, so pip no longer has it available, and the simplest solution is to use third-party wheels like the one pointed out by this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22651895/6622587 saying that it is not helpful does not help us understand you. Another option is to compile pyqt4 which is usually complicated for beginners