# Add QStyles to Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

I'm converting my GUI application from PyQt4 to PyQt5. But in PyQt4 we get so many QStyles like `plastique`, `Cleanlooks` etc. But in PyQt5 we have only `Fusion` style along with some plain old Windows styles.

How can we add more custom styles to PyQt5?

Comment: @eyllanesc I installed PyQt4 by first downloading it's wheel file and then running the pip command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640640/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-windows-using-pip#:~:text=For%20Windows%3A,%2F~gohlke%2Fpythonlibs%2F%23pyqt4&text=install%20PyQt5%20for%20Windows%2010%20and%20python%203.5%2B.&text=If%20you%20have%20error%20while%20installing%20PyQt4.  . For Pyqt5, I simply installed it using pip. My os is windows 10.

Comment: Good question. Pyside2 has similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of Qt's functionalities are implemented by plugins, and that is the case with styles. So in this case you must compile qtstyleplugins:

You can use the following procedure to compile qtstyleplugins:

- Install MSVC 2019 on Windows, XCode on MacOS and build-essential on Ubuntu (in case of another distro then you should look for the equivalent).
- Install Qt, the same version with which pyqt5 was compiled:  `python -c "from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR; print('Qt version', QT_VERSION_STR)"`.
- Clone the repository and then compile it by executing the following commands (in the case of windows you must change make to nmake):

  ```
  git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qtstyleplugins.git
  cd qtstyleplugins
  qmake 
  make 
  make install
  ```

These commands will generate the binaries (.so for Linux, .dll for windows and .dylib for MacOS) in folder "qtstyleplugins/plugins/styles/" that you must copy to the path:

```
python -c "import os; from PyQt5 import QtCore; print(os.path.join(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.PluginsPath), 'styles'))"
```

Output:

```
/home/qtuser/Documents/qt_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/styles
```

---

To facilitate the work I have created a github action that generates the binaries:

[**63477276.yml**](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/blob/master/.github/workflows/63477276.yml)

```
name: question_63477276

on: [push]

jobs:
  ci:
    name: ${{ matrix.os.name }} Python-${{ matrix.python }} Qt-${{ matrix.qt }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os.runs-on }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os:
          - name: Windows
            extension: "*.dll"
            runs-on: windows-latest
          - name: Linux
            extension: "*.so"
            runs-on: ubuntu-latest
          - name: MacOS
            extension: "*.dylib"
            runs-on: macos-latest
        python: [3.6, 3.7, 3.8]
        qt: [5.15.0]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Install Linux dependencies
        if: matrix.os.name == 'Linux'
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python }}
          architecture: x64
      - name: install pyqt5
        run: pip install pyqt5
      - name: before
        uses: GabrielBB/xvfb-action@v1.2
        with:
          run: python -c "from PyQt5 import QtWidgets; app = QtWidgets.QApplication([]); print(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys())"
      - name: Install Qt
        uses: jurplel/install-qt-action@v2
        with:
          version: ${{ matrix.qt }}
          dir: ${{ github.workspace }}/qt/
      - name: clone qtstyleplugins
        run: git clone https://code.qt.io/qt/qtstyleplugins.git
      - name: compile qtstyleplugins in Windows
        if: matrix.os.name == 'Windows'
        shell: cmd
        run: |
          call "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat"
          cd qtstyleplugins
          qmake
          nmake
          nmake install
      - name: compile qtstyleplugins in Linux or MacOS
        if: matrix.os.name == 'Linux' || matrix.os.name == 'MacOS'
        run: |
          cd qtstyleplugins
          qmake
          make
          make install
      - name: copy binaries
        run: python questions/63477276/search_binaries.py qtstyleplugins/plugins/styles/
      - name: after
        uses: GabrielBB/xvfb-action@v1.2
        with:
          run: python -c "from PyQt5 import QtWidgets; app = QtWidgets.QApplication([]); print(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys())"
      - name: upload
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          path: qtstyleplugins/plugins/styles/${{ matrix.os.extension }}
          name: qtstyleplugins-${{ matrix.os.name }}-Python${{ matrix.python }}-Qt${{ matrix.qt }}
```

and you can download the binaries for pyqt5 5.15 from [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/actions/runs/215464623).

Test:

```
python -c "from PyQt5 import QtWidgets; app = QtWidgets.QApplication([]); print(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys())"
```

Output:

```
['bb10dark', 'bb10bright', 'cleanlooks', 'cde', 'motif', 'plastique', 'windowsvista', 'Windows', 'Fusion']
```

Comment: all the links are expired, can't download anymore...pls help

Comment: @Voldemort That's what the script is for, run it and you will get the binaries