# PyQt4 : Module not foundError

Tags: pyqt4

I am trying to run a Python file that references PyQt4 using PyCharm. I get the following error message:

> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'

I am running a virtual environment and I tried installing PyQt4 in the venv's site-packages directory using the following command:

```
pip install pyqt4
```

However, the CMD window returns that it cannot return a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt4.

I checked the vendor's website and it states that in order to use the PyQt4, I need to install the SIP package and I did. But that didn't solve it either.

Comment: Why do you want to use a library that is no longer supported? Why don't you use pyqt5 or pyqt6?

Comment: Hi-yes I know that it is proceeded by PyQt5 and PyQt6. But, this is an existing project which I need to support its usage of all its dependencies and packages.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22651895/6622587

Comment: @Mohammad Try updating your existing project to PyQt5

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
PyQt5 or PySide2 or PySide6
```

like previously advised.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).